# Get the number inside span nested in a div

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

How can i get the number inside the span?

```
 <div id="num"><span>2</span></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var nr = document.getElementById('num').innerHTML;
 alert(nr);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, Use `textContent`

```
var nr = document.getElementById('num').textContent;
alert(nr); //op: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

**Updated :**
Correct way to get the text inside `Span` :

```
 var nrt =  document.getElementById('num'); 
 var nr =nrt.innerText||nrt.textContent;
 alert(nr);
```

Now it works for all,

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/66U7A/1/)

May this will help you..

Comment: Check my fiddle,I update it..On which browser you work ? it works correct for chrome !@CodeBird

Comment: alerts undefined for me.

Comment: Firefox alerts undefined, internet explorer alerts 2 though

Comment: Check it i make it compatible for all.. @CodeBird

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) to get the text inside the div.

```
var nr = document.getElementById('num').textContent;
```

or goto the son span and ask for its content

```
var nr = document.getElementById('num').childNodes[0].textContent;
```

If you don't know the other contents of the div, you could use regex to extract only the number from the text

```
var num = /\d+/.exec(document.getElementById('num').textContent)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
document.getElementById('num').firstChild.innerHTML
```

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LGLcc/).

Comment: Your code works, but @Krish R code is shorter and the answer was first.

Comment: No problem. It's not about reputation etc. Good luck in future!